# SAML Request send by wrong timezone

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on

I deploy my application .NET application IIS server and i try to use Single sign-on service

but the time when i see the SAML request is wrong time-zone

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
  ID="XX"
  Version="2.0"
  **IssueInstant="2023-01-23T06:14:45Z"** HERE THE ISSUE MUST BE +3 H FROM THE TIME ZONE
  Destination="XX"
  AssertionConsumerServiceURL="XX">
  <saml2:Issuer>XX</saml2:Issuer>
...
```

i check the time on the server is correct
[Picture of time in server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHvVz.png)

i went to the server and change in services (windows time) to auto
[windows services time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLtvc.png)

write time zone on SMAL request

Comment: is the SAML request generated by you code/server?

Comment: @Chetan  from the server